# Why is a difference between the Firebase Analytics and Google Big query Results for Events Counts how to resolve?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

There is an event for which Fire base shows events count for the day (16-Oct-2016) is 85989 and when i Query from Google Big Query. It shows on 25000 records from that particular event on the same day (16-Oct-2016). 
I used This Query to Get the data

```
**SELECT
date(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(event_dim.timestamp_micros)) AS Event_date
,event_dim.name as Event_Name
,Count(event_dim.name)as Total_Events
  FROM
    (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([MyDataSet imported from firebase],TIMESTAMP('2016-09-05'),TIMESTAMP('2016-10-24')))
  WHERE
    event_dim.name IN ('Specific Event Name')
  GROUP BY
    Event_Name,Event_date
    order by Event_date asc**
```

Why is this difference in the results Please help me to identify this.

Comment: What query did you run to get the number 25000? By event counts you mean number of times the event was triggered? Number of sessions that had the event? Or number of distinct visitors? Please share more information so we can help you

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Comment I have edited the Question and included the Query that i used. And yes I am looking for the  no.of time that event Triggered grouped by the date.

Comment: @user3709891, If you want to get the results for a single day, you can use the table name directly. (e.g.) SELECT event_dim.params.key FROM [com_android_example_ANDROID.app_events_20161024]. Then set the same date range filter in firebase analytics and tally the results.

Comment: @ArunVenkatesan I have also done this but still it shows me the different results i have set the date range on fire base for last 30 days and when i go to October 16 it shows me a huge difference data for the other days is also not same but close to the fire-base event Counts.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for people to help here, as we don't have access to your data sources.

So I suggest you to export raw data for that particular day from both sources, and compare them. Then you can find which one is incorrect, and then ask specific question to either firebase or google, like "My data source is like X, and my query is like Y, but I get unexpected result of Z".

Comment: Hi xuejian I have Edited my Question and included the more information